# scala concatenate string inside a list conditionally

Tags: scala

**Case1**: Given a Scala List of string

```
val l =List("@description", "AC", "T", "G", "+", "ZZZZ")
```

What's a good way to concatenate `"AC", "T", "G"`, the expected result is

```
List("@description", "ACTG", "+", "ZZZZ")
```

The rule is that starting from the second element, all strings should be concatenated until it hits another string that starts with `+`. It's related to [FASTQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) format parsing given that the sequence lines could be wrapped. The function is expected to be functional (aka. pure). I thought it might be implemented with `foldLeft`.

**Update**: Thank you for your answers! But I realized the problem a bit more complicated, the following cases should also work

**Case2**, input:

```
val l = List("@desc", "AA", "T", "+foo", "XX", "X", "@desc2", "TT", "C", "+bar", "Y", "YY")
```

expected output:

```
List("@desc", "AAT", "+foo", "XXX", "@desc2", "TTC", "+bar", "YYY")
```

So there can be multiple FASTQ records in the list. In the above case, there are two. The description line must start with `@`.

**Case3**:

input:

```
val l = List("@desc", "AAA", "TTT", "+foo", "@desc", "X", "@desc2", "TT", "C", "+bar", "+", "YY")
```

expected output:

```
List("@desc", "AAATTT", "+foo", "@descX", "@desc2", "TTC", "+bar", "+YY")
```

This is the most challenging case of the three since the quality lines (i.e. lines after the first line starting with "+") can also start with `@` or `+`. e.g. "@desc" is actually part of the quality instead of the starting line of another record. The way to distinguish between description and quality lines could be that the length of the sequence lines and that of the quality lines must match. In the third case, e.g. `"AAATTT".length === "@descX".length`, and also `"TTC".length == "+YY".length`

Comment: In case 3, does the ambigous quality lines always come in 2 segments?

Comment: also how many string with `+` is expected before new line?

Answer (score 1):

It certainly can be done with `foldLeft` but I thought that might get more complicated than the following.

```
def limitedConcat(ss: List[String]): List[String] = {
  val idx = ss.indexWhere(_.startsWith("+"))
  if (idx < 2) ss
  else ss.head :: ss.slice(1, idx).mkString :: ss.drop(idx)
}
```

This should work if the list is empty, if there is no `"+"` element, and also if, for some reason, the `"+"` element appears too early.

Answer (score 1):

```
  val l = List("@description", "AC", "T", "G", "+", "ZZZZ")
  val (prefix, suffix) = l.tail span (!_.startsWith("+"))
  val result = l.head :: prefix.mkString :: suffix
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add an answer that uses the oft-forgotten `span` function, which is also fairly efficient.

```
def conditionalConcat(strings: List[String]): List[String] = strings match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case head :: tail => head :: {
    val (beforePlus, afterPlus) = tail.span(!_.startsWith("+"))
    beforePlus.mkString :: afterPlus
  }
}
```

You can try it out in [ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/QpxdY8z/3)

Comment: What's the difference between `+:` and `::`? I am still not sure after reading the [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List)

Comment: `+:` is a method that is available to all `SeqLike` objects, whereas `::` is specific to `List`. The both prepend, but using `::` is supposed to guarantee O(1) complexity, whereas `+:` does not. This is helpful because when you refactor, you'd like to know if there's a chance you'll lose that guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list.span(!_.startsWith("+")) match {
  case (x::xs, rest) => x :: xs.mkString :: rest
  case (_, rest) => rest
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit what the second case does, please?

Comment: Second case required for case when list left part of span is empty, so it's pattern is not matched with x::xs. Without the second part it is unsafe for empty list

Answer (score 0):

I made it to work for all the three cases with the following two functions thought I think they can properly be refactored to look better

```
def extractQual(input: List[String], seqLength: Int, qual: String = ""): (String, List[String]) = {
    if (qual.length == seqLength) (qual, input)
    else if (qual.length > seqLength) ("", List())
    else extractQual(input.tail, seqLength, input.head + qual)
  }

def cleanFastqLines(lines: List[String], result: List[String] = List()): List[String] = lines match {
    case desc :: Nil => Nil
    case desc :: tail => {
      val (beforePlus, rest) = tail.span(_.head != '+')
      val seq = beforePlus.mkString
      val altDesc = rest.head
      val (qual, remained) = extractQual(rest.tail, seq.length)
      if (remained.nonEmpty) List(desc, seq, altDesc, qual) ::: cleanFastqLines(remained, result) ::: result
      else List(desc, seq, altDesc, qual) ::: result
    }
  }
```